# SharePoint Dev/Test environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to have a SP environment for developers to use to deploy and test their applications to for free? Please advise if this is possible and how to got about it.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is you can participate in the developer program of Office 365 . See 
[Join the Microsoft Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram).

Additionally, If you have MSDN subscription then you will get lot of benefits. You can check those benefits [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Benefits).

If you are open for paid SharePoint Online plan then you can [Compare SharePoint Online options](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans).